# Forbid any error typescript type in catch

Tags: typescript, eslint

Is there a way to forbid error being of type any or force annotate is as `error: unknown` by compiler oprtions/eslint?

```
function justDoIt(arg: string){}

// because error is any type this works :(
smth().catch(error => justDoIt(error))
```

Comment: Yeah, lots and lots of things are unfortunately typed as `any` instead of `unknown`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's an eslint rule which can enforce that you must use `unknown` in promise `.catch` handlers: https://github.com/cartant/eslint-plugin-etc/blob/main/docs/rules/no-implicit-any-catch.md

Additionally, if you're using typescript 4.0 or later, typescript [now supports](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-0-beta/#unknown-on-catch-clause-bindings) using `unknown` in try/catch blocks. So combined with async await you can do:

```
try {
  await smth();
} catch (error: unknown) {
  justDoIt(error); // disallowed by the types
}
```

And this can be enforced with a different eslint rule: https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-implicit-any-catch.md

Eslint config rules, first for try/catch, second for promise chain.

```
"@typescript-eslint/no-implicit-any-catch": ["error", { "allowExplicitAny": true }],
"etc/no-implicit-any-catch": ["error", { "allowExplicitAny": true }]
```

Comment: The `@typescript-eslint/no-implicit-any-catch` rule was removed in version 6 to favor using `unknown` in the catch: https://typescript-eslint.io/blog/announcing-typescript-eslint-v6/#rule-breaking-changes